# Faster composer install

Tags: php, composer-php

A composer install normally takes a few minutes. And on a production environment it's feels too slow. 
Is it possible to make a composer install to a temp directory and then switch it? If that is possible the downtime should be about zero.

Or are there any other way to do a composer install faster?

Comment: Sorry, but that is really weird. When you do `composer install` then your server is totally fresh and nobody accesses it, right ? Therefore this problem does not exist.

Comment: No, I have added the composer.lock file to my repo. When I'm running a composer install all the versions from my test environment is installed.

Comment: See my answer below.  As to the "downtime should be zero", you can accomplish this with automated deployment.  I use Capistrano and wrote a post about getting it up and running, including calling `composer install`: http://jeremykendall.net/2013/11/24/php-and-capistrano-3-notes-to-self/

Comment: I can't understand why this is being down voted.  I've been using Composer for some time, have blogged about it, and have presented on it. This is a legitimate and frequently asked question RE: Composer.

Comment: @Panique My experience with Composer has been that "Composer feels slow" is a frequent complaint with Composer users, one that simply calling `composer install` isn't enough to alleviate.  Not weird at all.

Comment: @JeremyKendall Is there a scenario where people do `composer install` on a in-use/traffic-receiving server ? Afaik the install is just for setup !? After the first install all you do is `update`ing, or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Panique Sadly, people do that all the time.  In production, one should only use `composer install`. That's mainly because `composer install` depends on `composer.lock` and will install known good versions of dependencies. `composer update` is, ideally, only used in dev. Furthermore (and to your point), `composer install` should be part of an automated deployment, one where the new version goes live only *after* all config and dependency installation is complete.

Answer (score 20):

I created a composer plugin to download packages in parallel.
https://packagist.org/packages/hirak/prestissimo

```
$ composer global require hirak/prestissimo
```

Please try it. In my environment, `composer install` become 10 times faster.

Comment: We use this and it's lovely. Thanks for disclosing your affiliation.

Comment: from 2m 11s to 2m 01s.. not very significant, our problem is the bandwidth and the number of vendors I guess

Comment: do you think this is usable on production servers ?

Comment: it's one of those times I wish SO had a <3 icon

Answer (score 4):

You can *sometimes* speed up `composer install` significantly by using the `--prefer-dist` flag, which just happens to be recommended for production use:

> **--prefer-dist**: Reverse of `--prefer-source`, composer will install from dist if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of the vendors.

`composer install` docs here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#install

**Edited To Clarify *Sometimes***

I say it *sometimes* speeds up `composer install` because there are plenty of factors that go into it feeling slow, not the least of which are network performance and the current Github status.  A slow install can be really frustrating, but it's not always b/c of Composer.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking two different and unrelated things.

Yes, it is a solution to build the next version of your site in a separate directory then put it in place after you moved the old version out of the way. It is, actually, the best solution.

This is how the deployment scripts I build work:

1. prepare the next version of the site in a separate directory (let's say `/var/www/new`); the following list of items and their order is not static, some projects need a different flow:

   - get the last version of the code from the repo;
   - remove the files that are not needed on the live site (`.gitignore`, IDE project files, placeholders etc);
   - run `composer install`;
   - copy/generate the configuration files containing the settings for the live servers (the ones stored in the repository contain dummy values);
   - change the user and permissions of all files; make some directories writable by the web server;
   - create symlinks, directories etc; for example, the directory that contains the user uploaded files is somewhere outside the server directory and a symlink to it is created during deploy to make its content available through the web server;
2. move the live code out of the way; I use `mv` to move the entire directory (`/var/www/html` to `/var/www/old`, for example);
3. move the prepared new version to the proper place (`mv /var/www/new /var/www/html`);
4. move the previous version into the archive (after I remove the content of `vendor` and other files that do not change or are external).

The advantages:

- the downtime is zero (microseconds, probably, between steps #2 and #3);
- a failed build doesn't affect the live site (if handled properly);
- reverting to the previous version (if needed) can be done easily.

---

Regarding the other question, the only way I know to speed `composer` up is to avoid running it using a PHP that loads the `xdebug` extension. The `xdebug` extension shouldn't be loaded on the production server anyway.